# Firestore: Getting collection with and without its sub-collection data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have collection of `charracters` where each document has some public data like username and character level, but also a private sub collection that has things like that characters gold amount.

Right now I can query characters collection for a specific document, but sub-collection data is not returned, so I need to perform a secondary query to retrieve it.

Is this the most optimal way to achieve this or is there a way to indicate that I also want to receive sub-collection data in the first query and sort of merge them together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Queries in Firestore are always shallow. There is no way to get documents from multiple different collection with a single query. So if you need to read from two collections, it will indeed at a minimum require two queries/read operations.

Comment: I see, I assumed since its a sub-collection there might be some sort of "trick" / "optimisation" in place to grab its data alongside main collection.

Comment: It's being considered, but there's lots of discussion on how it should work and the syntax. That reminds me, I think this was answered before, so I might mark as a duplicate after all.